# Attempting to instantiate multiple gameObjects in a spherical shape

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a dwarfFortress style world generation without the insane lore. basically, I want to randomly generate a world. I would also like to put this world on a globe where it can be viewed in a 3D environment.

so, my objectives are:

-randomly generate a 2D world out of quads (I am willing to use another shape!)

-wrap this world into a sphere shape

-select the individual tiles and interact with them

so far, I could not find anything very helpful.
I have tried to adjust the rotation of the quads and script in the position, but I could not get the math to work out for the life of me and This also causes some weird overlap with the edges of the quads near the top. I need to somehow distort the quads so they don't have edges protruding out of the "sphere."

next, someone (from reddit) recommended that I take a spherified cube and paint each quad onto the mesh using UV coordinates and a texture atlas. My only issue here is I'm not sure I would still be able to select each quad.

Is there any better way to go about doing this? If there is a way to put the whole gameObject on the spherified cube, how would one go about doing that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: *`wrap this world into a sphere shape`* You will never achieve this, spheres and planes are not topologically congruent.

Comment: is there a way I could achieve this by using hexagons? I was simply using quads for a quick example, but if I need another shape I'm open to.

Comment: Hexagons also tile on a flat plane, so also no. You have to approximate one way or another.